How to iterate through drop down website dropdown list?
I am writing a web scraping script to comb through items from a particular brand on the cvs website, the part I am stuck on is when I drill down to the page of an individual item that has multiple sizes/packs and I need to iterate through all the sizes in the list and get the URLs for each option I can only seem to get the second option only in the list or nothing at all
Above is the section identified as the dropdown block I am trying to iterate though when inspecting the website
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.cvs.com/shop/aveeno-daily-moisturizing-lotion-prodid-1013347?skuId=515049')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(15)

dropdown = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "search_select")
dropdown.click()
options = dropdown.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="select-dropdownContainer dswatchesMenuContainer"]')

for option in options:
    option.click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    print(driver.current_url)

Above is my code that when run I only get the second options URL in the drop down box printed, I have tried it on various other items on the site with more options and still only get the second option. I have also tried replacing the conditions in the options variable with:
//ul\[@class="variantsWithoutColorSwatchMobileContainer"\] with By.XPATH which also resulted in the same output of the url for the second option in the drop down box. and when i replace both arguments in the option variable with either:
By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li.select-option.select-optionRow',

By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.select-dropdownContainer.dswatchesMenuContainer'

Both returned no results whatsoever
How do I get the whole list of URLs in the drop down box? Where am I doing wrong?

The product data is embedded in <script id="variableScript"> which you can access from the productData variable.
import re
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import curl_cffi.requests as requests

req = requests.get(
    "https://www.cvs.com/shop/aveeno-daily-moisturizing-lotion-prodid-1013347?skuId=515049",
    impersonate="chrome110",
)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")
variable_script = soup.find("script", id="variableScript")
initial_state = re.search(r"var productData = (.*);", variable_script.string).group(1)
data = json.loads(initial_state)
print(data["options"])

{
   "__typename":"Product",
   "relationshipType":"Parent",
   "defaultSku":"515049",
   "handle":"aveeno-daily-moisturizing-lotion",
   "id":"1013347",
   "breadcrumbs":[],
   "images":[],
   "options":[
      {
         "id":"Group Size",
         "name":"Group Size",
         "values":[
            {
               "name":"8 Ounce",
               "value":"8 Ounce"
            },
            {
               "name":"12 Ounce",
               "value":"12 Ounce"
            },
            {
               "name":"18 Ounce",
               "value":"18 Ounce"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "price":{
      "currencyCode":"USD",
      "value":"9.59"
   },
... rest of the product data
}


this seems to work for the majority, however when i'm iterating through a list of items on the website i occasiuonally get the error:
`Cell In[17], line 38
36 soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")
37 variable_script = soup.find("script", id="variableScript")
---> 38 initial_state = re.search(r"var productData = (.*);", variable_script.string).group(1)
39 data = json.loads(initial_state)
41 return data['variants']
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string' `

an example url that gave me this error is : 'https://www.cvs.com/shop/flonase-children-s-24hr-allergy-relief-spray-50mcg-flucticasone-propionate-72-sprays-prodid-366337' , what is the reason for this?

You might be getting rate-limited, print out the text. The first error is Imperva blocking the req. And for the second one it only has one option so it's not embedded in options look at the full json and you will find where price is listed.

You are not getting options - you selector leads to dropdown container.
To click on each option and get correct url, you should do this:

Wait for dropdown to be present
Click on dropdown
Wait for all options to be present (options xpath is //div[@class="select-dropdownContainer dswatchesMenuContainer"]//*[@role="option"])
Execute loop for each index from options
Click on option
Wait until option object is stale (dropdown is closed)
Get url
If option is not last option, click on dropdown and re-init options elements array

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://cvs.com/shop/aveeno-daily-moisturizing-lotion-prodid-1013347?skuId=515049')
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

dropdown = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "search_select")))
dropdown.click()
options = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="select-dropdownContainer dswatchesMenuContainer"]//*[@role="option"]')))
for i in range(len(options)):
    options[i].click()
    wait.until(EC.staleness_of(options[i]))
    print(driver.current_url)
    if options[i] is not options[-1]:
        dropdown.click()
        options = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
            (By.XPATH, '//div[@class="select-dropdownContainer dswatchesMenuContainer"]//*[@role="option"]')))

